# Raphaël: Adding SVG Icon to Existing SVG Segments

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm trying to add svg icons to existing svg segments in an interactive wheel using Raphaël. I could just include the icon's svg into the segment's svg parameters but I need to style the icon differently and retain the existing interaction when the segment and icon are hovered over.

See the JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f4okjLee/2/

You will see that I have defined the icon object for my first segment "people" and given it new styling "iconStyle". It is visible behind the "people" segment though should overlay on top. Somehow I need to combine the segment and the icon and keep their styling separate (and repeat this for each segment using a different icon).

Anyone know how I do this?

```
    var R = Raphael("paper", 400, 400);


    var iconStyle = {
        fill: "#fff",
        stroke: "#fff",
        "stroke-width": 1,
        "stroke-linejoin": "round",
        cursor: "pointer"
    };


    var attr = {
        fill: "#333",
        stroke: "#fff",
        "stroke-width": 1,
        "stroke-linejoin": "round",
        cursor: "pointer"
    };


    var wheel = {};
    wheel.people = R.path("M205.1,84.2c-0.8-0.4-1.6-0.7-2.5-1.1c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2c-5.4-2.2-11-3.9-16.6-5 c-0.2,0-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.1c-5.7-1.1-11.5-1.7-17.3-1.7h-0.5c-4.7,0-9.4,0.4-14,1.1l-4.7-6.5l-0.8-1.1v0l-40.8-57 c9.1-3.5,18.4-6.2,27.9-8.1c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.1c10.5-2.1,21.2-3.1,31.9-3.1h0.5c10.7,0,21.4,1.1,31.9,3.1 c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.1c0.3,0.1,0.7,0.1,1,0.2l3.6,72v0l0.1,1.2v0L205.1,84.2z").attr(attr);

    wheel.leadEntrepreneur = R.path("M285,50l-0.3,0.6l-35.6,62l-0.6,1l-3.3,5.8c-0.5-0.8-1-1.7-1.6-2.5c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.4 c-3.2-4.7-6.9-9.2-11-13.4c0,0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.3c-4.2-4.1-8.7-7.8-13.4-11c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3 c-4.1-2.7-8.5-5.1-12.9-7.1l-0.3-6.2v0l-0.1-1.2v0l-3.6-72c10.1,2.1,20.1,5.1,29.7,9.1c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5,0.2 c9.8,4.1,19.3,9.1,28.3,15.1c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4,0.3c8.7,5.9,17,12.7,24.8,20.4C284.8,49.8,284.9,49.9,285,50L285,50z").attr(attr);
    wheel.assets = R.path("M330.4,134.2l-1.8,0.9l0,0l-1.7,0.8l0,0l-60.1,31.2l-1,0.5l-7,3.6c0-1.2,0.1-2.4,0.1-3.6c0-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.5 c0-5.8-0.6-11.6-1.7-17.3c0-0.2,0-0.3-0.1-0.5c-1.1-5.7-2.8-11.2-5.1-16.7c0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5c-1.8-4.4-4-8.7-6.6-12.8l3.3-5.8 l0.6-1l35.6-62L285,50c0,0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1c7.7,7.7,14.5,16,20.4,24.8c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.4c6,9,11.1,18.5,15.1,28.3 c0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5C325.2,113.9,328.3,124,330.4,134.2").attr(attr);
    wheel.marketNeed = R.path("M333.7,167.2v0.5c0,10.7-1,21.4-3.1,31.9c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.5c-2,9.9-4.8,19.6-8.6,29l-6.3-0.6h0l-1.8-0.2h0 l-63.6-5.9l-1.1-0.1l-7.9-0.7c0.7-1,1.5-2.1,2.2-3.1c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4c3.3-4.9,6-10,8.2-15.4c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.5 c2.3-5.4,3.9-11,5-16.7c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.5c0.9-4.5,1.4-9.1,1.6-13.7l7-3.6l1-0.5l60.1-31.2l0,0l1.7-0.8l0,0l1.8-0.9 c0,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.6c0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5C332.7,145.8,333.7,156.5,333.7,167.2").attr(attr);
    wheel.valuePrice = R.path("M322,229.2c-0.2,0.6-0.5,1.2-0.7,1.7c0,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.5c-4.1,9.8-9.1,19.3-15.1,28.3 c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4v0c-5.9,8.8-12.7,17-20.4,24.8c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3c0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1 c-6.7,6.7-13.9,12.8-21.4,18.1l-10.3-8.1h0l-1.3-1.1l0,0l-46.7-36.5l-0.8-0.7l-4.8-3.8c0.9-0.3,1.9-0.7,2.8-1.1 c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2c5.3-2.2,10.5-4.9,15.4-8.2c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4-0.3c4.7-3.2,9.3-6.9,13.4-11.1c0,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1 c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3c3.2-3.3,6.2-6.8,8.9-10.4l7.9,0.7l1.1,0.1l63.6,5.9h0l1.8,0.2h0L322,229.2z").attr(attr);
    wheel.supplyChain = R.path("M263.5,303.5c-1.1,0.8-2.2,1.6-3.4,2.3c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.4,0.3c-9,6-18.5,11.1-28.3,15.2 c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.2c-10,4.1-20.3,7.2-30.7,9.3c-0.2,0-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.1c-8.1,1.6-16.3,2.6-24.5,3l-7.5-21.4l-0.5-1.5 l-17.8-51.1l-0.4-1l-0.6-1.7c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.1,0.9,0.2c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.1c5.7,1.1,11.5,1.7,17.3,1.7h0.5 c5.8,0,11.6-0.6,17.3-1.7h0c0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.1c4.7-1,9.3-2.3,13.9-4l4.8,3.8l0.9,0.7l46.7,36.5l0,0l1.3,1.1h0L263.5,303.5z").attr(attr);
    wheel.legislatorsRegulators = R.path("M175.1,333.8c-2.5,0.1-5,0.2-7.5,0.2h-0.5c-10.7,0-21.4-1.1-32-3.1c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.1 c-10.5-2.1-20.7-5.2-30.7-9.3c-0.2,0-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2c-6.2-2.6-12.3-5.5-18.2-8.9l8-33.3l0.4-1.5l10.5-43.8c3.8,3.7,7.9,7,12.2,9.8 c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4,0.3c4.9,3.3,10,6,15.4,8.2c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.2c5.1,2.1,10.4,3.7,15.8,4.9l0.6,1.7l0.4,1l17.8,51.1 l0.5,1.5L175.1,333.8z").attr(attr);
    wheel.independantEndorsement = R.path("M104.1,233.7l-10.5,43.8l-0.4,1.5l-8,33.3c-3.4-2-6.8-4-10.1-6.2c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3 c-8.8-5.9-17.1-12.7-24.8-20.4l-0.4-0.4c-7.7-7.7-14.5-16-20.4-24.8c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.4c-2.8-4.3-5.5-8.6-7.9-13.1l33.4-32 l1.1-1l23.5-22.5c1,3.8,2.3,7.5,3.8,11.2c0,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5c2.2,5.3,5,10.5,8.2,15.4c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.4 c3.2,4.7,6.9,9.3,11.1,13.5c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3l0.1,0.1C103.2,232.9,103.6,233.3,104.1,233.7").attr(attr);
    wheel.underpinningScience = R.path("M77.7,185.6c0.4,1.8,0.8,3.6,1.3,5.4l-23.5,22.5l-1.1,1l-33.4,32c-2.7-5-5.1-10-7.2-15.2 c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5c-4.1-10-7.2-20.3-9.3-30.7c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.5C2,189.1,1,178.4,1,167.8v-0.5 c0-3.5,0.1-6.9,0.4-10.4l55.9-10.9h0l1.4-0.3h0l21-4.1c-0.8,2.6-1.4,5.2-2,7.9c0,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.5c-1.1,5.7-1.7,11.5-1.7,17.3 v0.5c0,5.8,0.6,11.6,1.7,17.3C77.6,185.3,77.6,185.4,77.7,185.6").attr(attr);
    wheel.intellectualProperty = R.path("M106.7,99.2c-1.3,1.1-2.5,2.3-3.7,3.5l-0.4,0.4c-4.2,4.2-7.9,8.7-11,13.4c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4 c-3.3,4.9-6,10-8.2,15.3c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.5c-1.2,2.9-2.2,5.8-3.1,8.8l-21,4.1h0l-1.4,0.3h0L1.4,156.8 c0.5-7.2,1.4-14.4,2.8-21.5c0-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.5c2.1-10.5,5.2-20.7,9.3-30.7c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.5c4.1-9.8,9.1-19.2,15.1-28.3 c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4c1.2-1.7,2.4-3.4,3.6-5.1l60.6,24.1l1.3,0.5L106.7,99.2z").attr(attr);
    wheel.money = R.path("M148.4,70.7l-0.8-1.1v0l-40.8-57c-0.9,0.4-1.9,0.7-2.8,1.1v0c-0.2,0-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.2 c-9.8,4.1-19.3,9.1-28.3,15.1c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.4,0.3C66,35.2,57.7,42,50,49.7c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3l-0.1,0.1 c-6.2,6.2-11.8,12.8-16.8,19.7l60.6,24.1l1.3,0.5l12,4.8c3.1-2.8,6.3-5.2,9.7-7.5c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4-0.3c4.9-3.3,10-6,15.4-8.2 c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2c5.4-2.2,11-3.9,16.6-5c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.1c1.1-0.2,2.2-0.4,3.3-0.6L148.4,70.7z").attr(attr);

    var icon = {};
    icon.people = R.path("M178.1,40.9l0-1.2c1.7,0.2,5.1-1,5.1-1c-1.2-1.2-1.4-2.6-2.2-8s-5.5-5.4-5.8-5.4c-0.4,0-5.1-0.1-5.8,5.4 c-0.8,5.4-1,6.8-2.2,8c0,0,3.4,1.2,5.1,1l0,1.2c-0.9,0.9-1.9,1.7-2.9,2.3c0.3,0.2,0.7,0.4,1,0.5c2.3,1.2,4.4,2.4,4.4,4.8v2.6h10.6 c0.4,0,0.7-0.3,0.7-0.7v-3C186,44.7,181,44.1,178.1,40.9 M164.8,41.2L164.8,41.2v-1c0.9-1,1.5-2.2,2-3.5c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.6c0.5-0.2,0.8-0.8,0.9-1.6 c0-0.3,0-0.5,0-0.7c-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.7-0.4-0.9c0-0.7,0-1.5,0-2.3c0-0.6-0.1-1.3-0.1-1.9c0-0.2,0-0.3-0.1-0.5 c-0.7-3.9-4.2-4.3-5.5-4.3c-0.1,0-1,0-1,0c-1.3,0-4.9,0.4-5.5,4.3c0,0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.5c-0.1,0.7-0.1,1.3-0.1,1.9 c0,0.8,0,1.6,0,2.3c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.5-0.4,0.9c0,0.2,0,0.5,0,0.7c0.1,0.8,0.5,1.4,0.9,1.6c0.1,0.4,0.2,0.8,0.4,1.2 c0.4,1.1,1,2.1,1.8,3v1c-3.3,3.6-8.8,4.3-8.8,7.3v3.3c0,0.4,0.3,0.7,0.7,0.7h23.4c0.4,0,0.7-0.3,0.7-0.7v-3.3 C173.6,45.5,168.1,44.8,164.8,41.2").attr(iconStyle);


    var current = null;
    for (var segment in wheel) {
        wheel[segment].color = "#005190";
        (function (st, segment) {
            st[0].onmouseover = function () {
                current && wheel[current].animate({fill: "#333", stroke: "#fff"}, 500) && (document.getElementById(current).style.display = "");
                st.animate({fill: st.color, stroke: "#005190", "stroke-width": 3}, 500);
                st.toFront();
                document.getElementById(segment).style.display = "block";
                current = segment;
            };
            st[0].onmouseout = function () {
                st.animate({fill: "#333", stroke: "#fff", "stroke-width": 1}, 500);
                st.toFront();
            };
            if (segment == "people") {
                st[0].onmouseover();
            }
        })(wheel[segment], segment);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if you mean something like https://jsfiddle.net/f4okjLee/3/ however, you need to either attach the mouseover to both icon and wheel and let them call the same function (so 2 handlers calling the same function, but check if animation is already running), or maybe move to Snap instead of Raphael (where you could set pointer-events: none as a style. I don't think you could do that on Raph as it has to support both VML and SVG.

Comment: Thank you, yes that looks correct. How do I sent two handlers to call the same function?

Comment: someIcon.mouseover( hoverFunc1 ) ; someWheel.mouseover( hoverFunc1 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do a couple of things IF you need to use Raphael (so can't use CSS pointer-events: none for example, as you need VML support).

Firstly, you don't need toFront() toBack() in this case as far as I'm aware, as you have already drawn the relevant parts in the right order.

You can add an event handler with 'mouseover', 'mouseout' and then call the 'same' function for both the icon and wheel. This would look something like the following (I have stripped some of the code out, just to highlight).

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f4okjLee/5/)

```
for (var segment in wheel) {
  wheel[segment].color = "#005190";
  wheel[segment].mouseover( myHover.bind(null, segment) )
  icon[segment].mouseover( myHover.bind(null, segment) )
  wheel[segment].mouseout( myHoverOut.bind(null, segment) )
  icon[segment].mouseout( myHoverOut.bind(null, segment) )
}

function myHover( type ) {
  wheel[ type ].animate({ fill: 'red' }, 1000);
  icon[ type ].animate({ fill: 'blue', transform: 's1.2' }, 1000);
}

function myHoverOut( type ) {
  wheel[ type ].animate({ fill: 'blue'}, 1000);
  icon[ type ].animate({ fill: 'red', transform: 's1' }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks! I have a few more questions. 1. I have set an animation on the wheel segments but hovering over them hides them under other segments. 2. How do I assign a different background color to each segment that I can reference in the myHover and myHoverOut functions?

Comment: I have just discovered how to manage layers:  wheel[ type ].toFront(); icon[ type ].toFront(); Update: https://jsfiddle.net/dpfc5r3u/1/